# Liferay Css User Status

Tags: css, liferay

i have got the following problem:

I want to create a new Liferay Theme and in this Theme there are Portlets in the Header, how can i Design these Portlets properly? My try was to deploy a "_unstyled" Theme and then copy the theme "classic" in "_diffs". This works fine and I have managed to get the most css done. But now i have a Login-Portlet in the Header and if the User is logged out , the Portlet has more "heigth" and so i cant use the same margin for these two cases.

My idea now was to add a .css file to my Css files and include this one as the last, which overrides the rest, if the user is logged in. This should be done in the portal_vm i guess, but since i am not familiar with the Liferay commands it would be nice if you could help me.

If this is just a little bit of Code, please give me a short example.

Im working with Liferay 6.1 and Eclipse.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a "signed-in" and a "signed-out" class on body depending if someone is signed in or not.

So you might be able to just use this in custom.css

```
.signed-in .portlet-login {
  margin: 0px;
}

.signed-out .portlet-login {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

of course, change the margins and other values according to your environment.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i needed , is there a list with the classes liferay uses? I searched the documentation but maybe i looked up the wrong words, a Link would be enough thx.

Comment: I'm not aware of a definitive list, but firebug is your friend here (or the equivalent for your browser of least distrust). You can use the same technique for browsers and color schemes in Liferay: ".ie6 body { background: red; }" works well. The proper tip, I guess, is to browse through the DOM (with firebug) and get an idea what you can use to your advantage. This teaches you more (and you'll discover so much more at the side) than a list of definitive classes.